# Prove if $ac>bc$ and $c>0$, then $a>b$

Tags: inequality, axioms

How can I prove that if $ac>bc$ and $c>0$, then $a>b$ without division?
Or Should I prove it by contrapositive?

Comment: Yes, explain why if $a$ is not larger than $b$, then you cannot have $ac>bc$.

Comment: Totally depends on what axioms and definitions you are working with.

Comment: what are you allowed to use in the proof (which axioms, these for the reals?) and what is the definition of ">" ?

Comment: Argue that if $a\le b$ then $ac\le bc$ (two cases to deal with).

Answer (score 5):

of $ac>bc$,  it follows that $ac-bc>0$ and $(a-b).c>0$. Knowing that the data numbers $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $x.y>0$, then  $x$ and $y$ are either positive or negative, i.e, $x,y>0$ or $x,y<0$.

By hypothesis, $c>O$, and so $a-b>0$. Therefore, $a>b$, which solves the problem.

Comment: +1, though I guess the problem is about "$\in\mathbb R$" rather than "$\in\mathbb Z$"

Comment: As he spoke, I assumed it would be in $Z$, but thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

$$
ac> bc 
$$
$$
c(a-b) \gt 0
$$

$$
\text{two cases: }
(c\gt 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad a-b\gt 0) \quad \text{ or } \quad (c \lt 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad  a-b \lt 0)
$$

and because $$c \gt 0$$ then $$a-b\gt 0$$